# create object and object length

Tags: javascript, jquery

element length

In the console, I entered "$reminder_blank.length", and then the answer is just one. I tried to inspect where that element was in. It is always the last element. May I know why? I expect the length is 3...
Thank you

```
const $reminder_blank= $('<p>This input field cannot be blank.</p>');
$( "[type='text']").after($reminder_blank);
```

```
 <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">

    <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
    <input id="zip" name="user_zip" type="text"> 
    <label for="cc-num">Card Number:</label>
    <input id="cc-num" name="user_cc-num" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a full HTML string (*not* a selector string) to jQuery (`$`), that will create an element associated with the jQuery object the result is assigned to. With your

```
const $reminder_blank = $('<p>This input field cannot be blank.</p>');
```

jQuery will create a `<p>` element associated with `$reminder_blank`. Only one element has been created.

If you then use `.after` to insert elements into the DOM, jQuery will *clone* the single element in `$reminder_blank` and insert it after each of the other matched elements (here, those matching the `"[type='text']"` selector string), except the last - the last element `.after` is called on will be given the element originally in `$reminder_blank`. So, all but the final element inserted [will be clones](https://api.jquery.com/after/):

> **Important:** If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except for the last one.

If you want to select all elements inserted, use the selector string `[type='text'] + p`:

```js
const $reminder_blank = $('<p>This input field cannot be blank.</p>');
$("[type='text']").after($reminder_blank);

const $insertedReminders = $("[type='text'] + p");
console.log($insertedReminders.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">

<label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
<input id="zip" name="user_zip" type="text">
<label for="cc-num">Card Number:</label>
<input id="cc-num" name="user_cc-num" type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So, do you mean that clone copy is not regarded as an object?

Comment: Not at all, a cloned object is still an object.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Your answer is very detailed.

Comment: It seems I cannot vote because I am a new member in stackoverflow. I sincerely appreciate your help